# NextQuestion button only works on the first question, then it's disabled

Tags: javascript, button, onclick, disable

Hi I'm a beginner at coding but I need to make a quiz as  an assignment. It works well but I wanted to **enable the NextQuestion button only when user clicks the right answer** (turns green) - if their answer is wrong (turns red), they should try picking another one till they click the right one. Until then they should not be able to move on to the next question.

I have no idea how to do it, I've only tried what I have as the nextQuestion function, but it only works for the 1st question. **When I move to the 2nd question, the Next Question button doesn't work at all - like it's permanently disabled.**
Note: I've made the answers as buttons (btn1, btn2, btn3, btn4), I found it easier to work with this way.
Note 2: In the html file, it's:

> < button class="next" id="nextBtn" onclick="nextQuestion()">Next
> Question </ button >

Here is my code (please don't mind my questions and answers, they're only for me to see if everything works fine :) ) :

```
let Questions;
Questions = [
  {
id: 0, 

q: "2+3", 

a: [ 

  { text: "3", isCorrect: "False" }, 

  { text: "4", isCorrect: "True" }, 

  { text: "5", isCorrect: "False" }, 

  { text: "6", isCorrect: "False" }, 

],
```

}
{

```
id: 1, 

q: "question2", 

a: [ 

  { text: "x", isCorrect: "False" }, 

  { text: "y", isCorrect: "False" }, 

  { text: "z", isCorrect: "False" }, 

  { text: "w", isCorrect: "True" }, 

],
```

},

{

```
id: 2, 

q: "qwerty", 

a: [ 

  { text: "a", isCorrect: "False" }, 

  { text: "i", isCorrect: "False" }, 

  { text: "u", isCorrect: "True" }, 

  { text: "j", isCorrect: "False" }, 

],
},
```

{

```
id: 3, 

q: "q number 4", 

a: [ 

  { text: "a", isCorrect: "False" }, 

  { text: "i", isCorrect: "False" }, 

  { text: "u", isCorrect: "True" }, 

  { text: "j", isCorrect: "False" }, 

],
```

},

];

let start = "True";

let selected = document.getElementById("selected");

let btn1 = document.getElementById("btn1");

let btn2 = document.getElementById("btn2");

let btn3 = document.getElementById("btn3");

let btn4 = document.getElementById("btn4");

function iterate(id) {

let question = document.getElementById("question");

question.innerText = Questions[id].q;

btn1.innerHTML = Questions[id].a[0].text;

btn2.innerHTML = Questions[id].a[1].text;

btn3.innerHTML = Questions[id].a[2].text;

btn4.innerHTML = Questions[id].a[3].text;

btn1.value = Questions[id].a[0].isCorrect;

btn2.value = Questions[id].a[1].isCorrect;

btn3.value = Questions[id].a[2].isCorrect;

btn4.value = Questions[id].a[3].isCorrect;

btn1.addEventListener("click", () => {

```
clearButtonStyles(); 

selected.innerHTML = btn1.value; 

btn1.style = 

  btn1.value === "False" 

    ? "background:red;color:white;" 

    : "background:green;color:white;";
```

});

btn2.addEventListener("click", () => {

```
clearButtonStyles(); 

selected.innerHTML = btn2.value; 

btn2.style = 

  btn2.value === "False" 

    ? "background:red;color:white;" 

    : "background:green;color:white;";
```

});

btn3.addEventListener("click", () => {

```
clearButtonStyles(); 

selected.innerHTML = btn3.value; 

btn3.style = 

  btn3.value === "False" 

    ? "background:red;color:white;" 

    : "background:green;color:white;";
```

});

btn4.addEventListener("click", () => {

```
clearButtonStyles(); 

selected.innerHTML = btn4.value; 

btn4.style = 

  btn4.value === "False" 

    ? "background:red;color:white;" 

    : "background:green;color:white;";
```

});

}

function clearButtonStyles() {

btn1.style = "";

btn2.style = "";

btn3.style = "";

btn4.style = "";

}

if (start) {

iterate(0);

}

let newGame = document.getElementsByClassName("newGame")[0];

newGame.addEventListener("click", () => {

id = 0;

iterate(0);

clearButtonStyles();

})

let nexBtn = document.getElementById("nextBtn");

let next = document.getElementsByClassName("next")[0];

let id = 0;

function nextQuestion() {

if (selected.innerHTML === "True") {

```
document.getElementById("nextBtn").disabled = true; 

clearButtonStyles(); 

id++; 

iterate(id);
```

} else {

```
document.getElementById("nextBtn").disabled = false;
```

}

}

Comment: Sorry I had no idea how to properly paste my code...

Comment: "_Sorry I had no idea how to properly paste my code..._" See [/help/formatting](/help/formatting) and [/editing-help](/editing-help):)